# Iterative sampling from a list using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

So I have the following issue. The code below, using the current value of the state vector, does some iterative sampling from list M to determine the next value of the state vector. The code works. However, for far larger lists M, the sampling process takes a very long time. I read that by using the Rcpp package you can speed up the process significantly. However, after working on it for quite a few hours, I'm stuck! Not only does it seem that C++ doesn't have a similar sample function, but also data manipulation and accessing in C++ is not as easy as in R. So how could the seemingly simple code below be converted by using the Rcpp package? Any help is imensely appreciated!!!

```
state <- c(2, NA, NA, NA)
M <- list(matrix(c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1), nrow = 3, 
     ncol = 3), matrix(c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1), 
     nrow = 3, ncol = 3), matrix(c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 
     0.1), nrow = 3, ncol = 3))

for (i in 1:3) {

state[i + 1] <- sample.int(3, size = 1, prob = M[[i]][state[i], ])

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may want to look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, what C++ code have you tried? What were the specific problems or error messages you got? Also, you should check out the excellent [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/). It has articles on [`sample()`](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-the-Rcpp-based-sample-implementation/) and an example of a [Gibbs sampler](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/gibbs-sampler/), which may be similar enough to what you're doing to get you started.

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue? The function `Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample()` mentioned by @duckmayr should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: BTW, you should definitely profile your code! Recent RStudio versions have very nice GUI support for profiling. Depending on the location of the bottleneck, you might gain much by using Rcpp.